# How to start from zero

Tags: boot

I've had Ubuntu for a couple years but I didn't use it much [Also I forgot most of the passwords] so I was wondering how to delete all my files and profiles and just start from the beginning. I'm not the best with computers so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean how to install/reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: Download the latest disk image and install, I suppose.

Comment: Yes reinstall it. Fossfreedom

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest will be to do a clean reinstall. If you have not used it for quiet a wile there cant be anything important in it.

Comment: Is there a command for that, or do I need a disc to do that?

Comment: No, there isn't really a way to do a clean install of the system while you're running it. The OS simply can't overwrite itself. You can download the latest version (13.04) or the latest long-term-support version 12.04, burn the iso to a bootable live DVD or USB, and boot from that. Then you can overwite the hard disk with the latest version while running off the DVD or USB.